# How i can download a data from an Api

Tags: android, api, kotlin

`Hi i use this Api`

```
https://hadeethenc.com/api/v1/hadeeths/one/?language=en&id=3710
```

the number 3710 change...
and the data that return to you from this api is fixed it doesn't change.so i'm wondring if i can just download this data to use it in my app without the need for internet.
and thanks

Comment: Technically, the answer is probably yes. It depends a bit on how much of the data you need and where you are going to store it on the app. But there might also be some legal issues associated with the API which may not allow you to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you want to cache the data. You can achieve it by using room database. just create a table with the id as the primary key and whenever the user tries to make a network call just check the table if any row with the same id exists. if it exists then show the data present in that row if there is no row with the said id then make the API call and insert the data received from the API into the table.

Comment: thanks but is that work without internet and could you tell me more how to do that in kotlin

Comment: yeah, check this link out [link](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room) it shows how to use room database.

Comment: If you want more resources you can check this [link](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLrnPJCHvNZuCLOE6tNcoOHSJ5rvhi0t0p) youtube playlist out, I think he is doing what you want to, your fetch function and entity will be different from what he is doing.

Comment: thanks  buddy i really apreciate it